# Set custom master pages in sharepoint-hosted apps

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-apps

I want to use custom master pages in SharePoint-Hosted apps. 
I followed this article: http://anthony-verschraegen.blogspot.fi/2013/03/sharepoint-2013-apps-custom-app-master.html
But after my solution deployment to site collection (Myportal/sites/apps) i get File Not Found error. How to solve this problem?

Answer (score 2):

Specify your solution structure and URL details will help your question get answer correctly.

Sometime the mismatching, typo in some path will lead you to this error. Within your provided information, I suggest that you should perform the following check:

Check the Module **element.xml** file: Module Name, File Path, File Url

```
<Module Name="MasterPage">
             <File Path="MasterPage\appNew.master" Url="_catalogs/masterpage/appNew.master" ReplaceContent="TRUE" /></Module>
```

Check the **.aspx** file:
Remember the path: "~site/_catalogs/masterpage/"

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~site/_catalogs/masterpage/appNew.master" Inherits="Microsoft.SharePoint.WebPartPages.WebPartPage, Microsoft.SharePoint, Version=15.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c" %>
```

Check the **package.package** file: Does the MasterPage module added to any of your features ?

After make sure the above correct, please let me know if you're still facing this problem.